# Get full link from page with Scrapy

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, hyperlink, scrapy

I want to get torrents links from page. With chrome source browser I see the link is:

```
href="browse.php?search=Brooklyn+Nine-Nine&amp;page=1"
```

But then i scrap this link with Scrapy i only get:

```
href="browse.php?page=1"
```

this "search=Brooklyn+Nine-Nine&" part is not in the link.

Into page's torrents search form I enter "Brooklyn Nine-Nine", and it will show all search results.

So my question will be is it chromes automatic links formatting feature? and how I could get link with Scrapy as Chromes shows. 
I think i could enter missing part by my self. Such like replacing spaces with plus sign in text that is used for search. 
Or maybe were there some more elegant solution...

Answer (score 0):

It's all okey... I did a mistake in my script. My search text was empty so the links also was without any additional text.

Comment: If question is not needed I suggest you to cancel it